# How do I assign a variable to context.fillStyle

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

I am trying to make rectangles appear randomly on a canvas, and am trying to make the colors of the rectangles be chosen randomly from the array colors. It works when I set the value of context.fillstyle to a color, but when I set the value of context.fillStyle to RandomColor, the rectangles become black. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function init(){
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
var width = Math.floor(Math.random()*300)+1;
var height = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+1;
var colors = ["green", "blue", "red", "pink", "yellow"]
var randomColor = colors[Math.floor((Math.random)*colors.length)];
context.fillStyle = randomColor;
context.fillRect(x,y,width,height);
}
</script>
<form>
<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="init()">
< /form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change Math.random into Math.random(). You forgot to parentheses and are therefor not calling the random function.

```
function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var width = Math.floor(Math.random() * 300) + 1;
    var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var colors = ["green", "blue", "red", "pink", "yellow"]
    var randomColor = colors[Math.floor((Math.random()) * colors.length)];
    context.fillStyle = randomColor;
    context.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
}
```

See the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YJ52J/)

By printing the output to the console you would have found it...

```
console.log(Math.floor((Math.random()) * colors.length)) // -> NaN
```